# Javascript literal vs function oop

Tags: javascript, oop, literals, prototype-programming

whats the best practice to use these?

```
var x = { a: 'a', eat: function() { }, ... }
```

vs

```
var x = function() { var a = 'a'; this.eat = function() { }}
```

the above needs to be initiated:

```
new x();
```

can someone help me explain the importance of the two, and which one is preferred choice within the oop community? any word of wisdom would help. i also did some research but nothing came up. much thought is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic difference is that the first version exposes the variable 'a', while the second one hides it.  So unless you want or need client code to access `x.a`, the second version is preferred.

A third approach would be to use a prototype.  In this case, a local variable in the constructor won't do you much good, so if `eat()` needs access to `a`, then you'd write:

```
function x() {
    this.a = 'a';
}

x.prototype.eat = function() {
    // do stuff with this.a
}
```

In this case, each instance has a new copy of `a`, but there's only one copy of `eat`.  The drawback (if you consider it one) is that `a` is available to users of `x` instances.

Comment: However, the 2nd version doesn't allow for use of [[prototype]] (which the 1st *could* be trivially converted into) -- with the 2nd approach each `eat` will therefor be a new function-object with a new bound [[scope chain]]. I generally prefer to use the [[prototype]].

Comment: yeah, but he can always do
`var x = (function(){ var a = 'a'; return { eat: function(){} }; }());`

Comment: can you give an example of how the prototype would look like?

Comment: Good points.  It wasn't clear from the question whether new closures were wanted in each case, since the function has no code.  Technique aside, though, it's clearly better 'oop' to hide internals when possible.

Answer (score 3):

The first one will just create a single object, you can't use it with the `new` keyword. The second one contains a local variable `a` instead of creating a property like the first one.

Functions are usually written as named functions instead of anonymous functions assigned to variables:

```
function x() {
  this.a = 'a';
  this.eat = function() {};
}
```

Now you can create objects using it:

```
var y = new x();
```

Another way of specifying methods for the object is to put it in the prototype:

```
function x() {
  this.a = 'a';
}

x.prototype.eat = function() {};
```

Comment: Actually, the "anonymous functions assigned to variables" is called a function expression, and is fairly common.

Comment: @Bradley Staples: No, a *function expression* is not an *anonymus function assigned to a variable*, the anonymous function is one form of a function expression, so an *anonymous function assigned to a variable* is one form of a *function expression assigned to a variable*. Although it's fairly common, named functions is way more common.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it depend on what you are trying to get. Remember, that JS has no real classes, its prototype based language. Operator `new` is quite misleading.

I would suggest using literal `{}` whenever it is possible. In example, you could do it like this:

```
var myconstr = function(param){
    var pr = 'some private var';
    return {
         a : param,
         get2a : function(){ return this.a; }
    };
};
```

If you want only one instance, you could always call this function just after defining it.

BUT if you want to use `prototype`, it could be easier with Construction function - but still, i wouldn't use new operator as is, maybe wrapping it in some other func would be better.